# Part of the question & answers are now hidden by blog & other details on the right

Tags: bug, status-completed, site

I'm not used to writing questions; but the site is offering me Similar questions above where I'm typing, but I cannot read much of the text as the right side of it is covered by the "How to format" which has a yellow background that makes text underneath it unreadable.

I cannot read all of comments on questions, or all of questions anymore at my chosen setting (100% or standard zoom) as the "Blog" and "Related" to the far right of the screens just covers the text I want to read & also makes it impossible to copy & paste into a text editor, as it won't let me copy what I want alone, but also selects the whole right side of blog/related..

If this was a change as I suspect it was, it's made the site unusable.

[image]

My browser is Chromium, on Lubuntu 20.04  (it reports Chromium 78.0.3904.108 snap)

Comment: ps:  I hope some of you can read my ramble - I can only read the left & middle of it, the right being covered by Blog & it's yellow background...

Comment: I think a screenshot would greatly help people (and SE) to understand the details of your bug report.

Comment: The issue is network wide. It was reported on [meta.se] 1 hour ago. See [Strange overlapping post-layout and sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339651/468333) and [Content running off page on responsive version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339652/468333)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) up on Meta.SE, indicating this issue has been fixed network wide 15 hours ago.